# materialui dropdown menu doesn't update every second

Tags: reactjs

this is how I get my local time, per second:

```
  const istanbulDate = today.toLocaleTimeString(locale, { hour: 'numeric', hour12: false, minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', timeZone:"Europe/Istanbul" });
```

And this is the materialui dropdown section:

```
<MenuItem value={istanbulDate}>Turkey</MenuItem>
```

But it doesn't update every second when I render it in a MenuItem value. Otherwise, it works perfectly and updates the local time every second.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because the component is rendered only once and would require a re-render.

> Define a setInterval with an interval of 1sec(1000ms) and use a state variable to store the value of istanbulDate then, on every interval update the value of your state.

This will work 100%

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it gives me white screen error. Here is my code: <MenuItem value={() => {
            
            setInterval(() => {
              
              setIstanbulDate(prevDate => prevDate)

            }, 1000);
            return {istanbulDate}
            
          }}>{istanbulDate}</MenuItem>

Comment: No this wont work you need to define setInterval in a useEffect hook

Comment: Thank you for reply. But it's still not working. It renders the time but no update.

Comment: Can you post the new code here

Comment: I have posted it as an answer to this topic. Thank you for your interest by the way.

Answer (score 0):

[seen in the image, it renders every second while it is put on between tags (<>), but it's not working while it is in the value={} tag.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mapbq.png)

```
<MenuItem value={() => {
        
          return <p>{istanbulDate}</p>
        
      }}>{istanbulDate}</MenuItem>
```

Seen above, the istanbulDate that is returned, is rendering only once and doesn't update every second. But the istanbulDate that is in the below, around <> tags, renders every second and gives me an update.

What I believe is, there is a problem with value={} method, somehow it doesn't get updated.

Comment: Let me know if this works.If it done please close this thread.

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: can you repost your new code

Answer (score 0):

@PRATIK NAIK, here is the code:

Here is the useEffect part:

```
    const [today, setDate] = React.useState(new Date());
  const [istanbulDate, setIstanbulDate] = React.useState("")

  React.useEffect(() => {
      const timer = setInterval(() => {

      setDate(new Date())

       setIstanbulDate(prevDate => today.toLocaleTimeString(locale, { hour: 'numeric', hour12: false, minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', timeZone:"Europe/Istanbul"}))

      
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, []);
```

Here is the MaterialUI value part:

```
const [firstValueState, setFirstValueState] = React.useState("")    

function handleFirstChange(event){
        setFirstValueState(prevstate => event.target.value)
    }

<div className="timeCard">
          <Box sx={{minWidth: 120 }} size="large">
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="country">Country</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="country"
          id="country-select"
          value={firstValueState}
          countryImg="countryimg"
          label="Country"
          onChange={handleFirstChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={() => {

            setInterval(() => {
              
              return {istanbulDate}

            }, 1000);

          }}>Turkey</MenuItem>
```

The main point in this, is that {istanbulDate} perfectly works and updates itself every second when it's not used in a value statement that created by MaterialUI.
But I want to use it on value statement, because I want users to select a country from a dropdown menu, and render the related time of the related country on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

export default function Countryddl(props){

    const locale = 'en';
    const [today, setDate] = React.useState(new Date());
    const istanbulDate = today.toLocaleTimeString(locale, { hour: 'numeric', hour12: false, minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', timeZone:"Europe/Istanbul" });
    const caymanDate = today.toLocaleTimeString(locale, { hour: 'numeric', hour12: false, minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', timeZone:"America/Cayman" });


    React.useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
                setDate(new Date());
      }, 1000);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(timer); // Return a funtion to clear the timer so that it will stop being called on unmount
      }
    }, []);

    var countrylist = [
        {
            value:1,
            label:`Turkey ${istanbulDate}`,
            time:`Türkiye'de saat: ${istanbulDate}`
        },
        {
            value:2,
            label:"Cayman Islands",
            time:`Kayman adalarında saat:${caymanDate}`
        }
    ];

    const [result, ddlvalue] = useState(countrylist.time)
    const ddlHandler = e => 
    {
        ddlvalue(e.label);
    }
    return(
        <div>

        <Select options={countrylist} onChange={ddlHandler}/>
            <h1>{result}</h1>
        </div>

    );
    }
```

I tried to do it without using MaterialUI, with a simple select and option tag.

The problem can be seen in the video: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/10819073?key=6c539cf6e3ae72d194be40f94a229b89

It gets updated while dropdown menu is on, but the result is stable.

Answer (score 0):

> You dont need to add another setInterval in value prop of MenuItem simply use instanbulDate there.Take a look here:

```js
const [firstValueState, setFirstValueState] = React.useState("")    

function handleFirstChange(event){
        setFirstValueState(prevstate => event.target.value)
    }

<div className="timeCard">
          <Box sx={{minWidth: 120 }} size="large">
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="country">Country</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="country"
          id="country-select"
          value={firstValueState}
          countryImg="countryimg"
          label="Country"
          onChange={handleFirstChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={istanbulDate}>Turkey</MenuItem>
```

Comment: This does not work.